# Check format of dateTime matches custom format ("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss") - Java

Tags: java, datetime

I'm writing a test to check if the dateTime returned from pinging a database is the expected format.

The format I want is "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss".

My current code is using a DateTimeFormatter to define the custom format it should match and then parse the dateTime returned from the pinging. An assertion assertEquals is used to check they are the same format.

However, I am getting an exception as the formatter is returning the incorrect format:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected:2021-08-10T17:18:53
Actual:10/18/2021 17:18:53
```

As you can see the expected format is not what it should be.

This is my current code

```
String dateTime = JsonPath.read(res.getResponse().getContentAsString(),"$.[0].datetime");

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
LocalDateTime parsedDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTime,formatter);

try {
     Assert.assertEquals(parsedDateTime, dateTime);
} catch (AssertionError e){
     throw e;
}
```

Comment: `dateTime ` is a String and `parsedDateTime` is a LocalDateTime - why do you think they will be equal?

Comment: `LocalDateTime.parse` will throw an exception if the format is incorrect. You don't need to check for the correct pattern yourself.

Comment: *check if dateTime returned from pinging a database is the expected format* will be undertaken by the `LocalDateTime.parse` - if if fails you will know.

Comment: Even if were of the same datatype, one's got a `T` in the middle, the other not…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’d go for this in the following way:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter PARSER
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.ROOT);

@Test
public void correctFormatReceived() {
    String dateTime = "10/18/2021 17:18:53"; // get from JSON
    LocalDateTime.parse(dateTime, PARSER);
}
```

`LocalDateTime.parse()` will throw a `DateTimeParseException` if the format is incorrect, which JUnit or your test runner will then report.

If you want strict validation of the date and time value (detect if they send February 29 in a non-leap year, for example), specify so on the formatter:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter PARSER
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.ROOT)
                .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT);
```

If you want to distinguish clearer between an incorrect format and your test failing to run to completion, catch the exception and declare a test failure:

```
try {
    LocalDateTime.parse(dateTime, PARSER);
} catch (DateTimeParseException dtpe) {
    Assert.fail(dtpe.toString());
}
```

### What went wrong in your test?

As others have said in comments, in Java, a `String` can never be equal to a `LocalDateTime`. So your `Assert.assertEquals(parsedDateTime, dateTime);` would fail under all circumstances. Also, being able to parse the string at all is enough to determine that the specified format is as expected; so in your test, you don’t need to test for any equality.

Comment: Isn't the resolver style `ResolverStyle.STRICT` by default?

Comment: @MCEmperor - No. `ResolverStyle.SMART` is the default. Check the following line: `The smart option is the default.` at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)

Comment: @MCEmperor Some (most or all?) of the predefined formatters are `STRICT`, which might have contributed to the confusion. The ones we define ourselves from format patterns are `SMART`, as Arvind said.